# Using $dayOfYear on method find() with MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I need to do a query where i can get all row with the year using  MongoDB.

Row:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("53a3733dfbea7787f4b4e8f6"),
    "_class" : "demo.model.User",
    "name" : "Tiare",
    "created" : ISODate("2014-06-19T23:33:17.000Z")
}
```

Example:

```js
db.user.find({"created" : {$year : "2014"}})
db.user.find({"created" : {$dayOfYear : "170"}})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operators you are referring to are [date aggregation operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) and are reserved for use in the [aggregation framework](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) and cannot be used with other methods. They have a different purpose which is to "dissect" the dates for aggregation on common intervals such as in:

```js
db.user.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": { "$year": "$created" },
            "day": { "$dayOfYear": "$created" }
        },
        "count": { "$sum" 1 }
    }}
])
```

What you seem to want is selecting all documents within your required date "range". You do this with the [**`$gt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/) and [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operators and [cousins](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/):

```js
db.user.find({
    "created": { "$gte": new Date("2014-01-01"), "$lt": new Date("2015-01-01") }
})
```

Which in that example fetches all the dates that occur within "2014"

If you really wanted to see if something like if there was a "200th" day within your data for the year then you could do something like this using aggregate:

```js
db.user.aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
           "year": { "$year": "$created" },
           "day": {
               "$cond": [
                   { "$eq": [ {"$dayOfYear": "$created"}, 200 ] },
                   {"$dayOfYear": "$created"},
                   false
               ]
           }
    }}
])
```

Which would only return you a result in "day" with the matched "dayOfYear" or `false` if that did not exist in any date value. That would be the most efficient way.

You could also [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) but that is not very efficient as you need to process all of the results out of your "projection".

But generally try to stick with the "range" queries on the dates as it is the most efficient way to do things, especially when you have an index.

Comment: Using aggregation this example is better: "db.user.aggregate({$project : {"year" : {$dayOfYear : "$created"} }});". I would like to confirm if don't exist a way for i give this information on the find method.

Comment: @TiarêBalbi The operators are only for use with aggregation. You could use aggregate to report back `$dayOfYear` and then filter on only certain values present, but it would be more efficient to do this using `.find()` with a range query as shown. Unless you find it easier just to specify a "day of year" such as "200" without working out which "date" that was. Is this what you need help with?

Comment: Do you know if using $group when the condition is true i can return the record instead of the field with the total value?

Comment: @TiarêBalbi Just replace the second argument in `$cond` with all of the fields wrapped in the object. The results are likely to be "days" rather than a single document. Since this would likely be many results then it is not going to be efficient to filter out the `false` result. Again, find on a date range is the better option. Use external functions to calculate the dates from the "day of year" you have to input. It's much faster than trying to brute force aggregate into doing this.

Comment: missing a ":" in the line `"count": { "$sum": 1 }`